# Where can I get a WMS or WFS for near-real time Wind (atmospheric) data?

Tags: data, wms, wfs

I've been looking for a good operational WMS or WFS free service to access near-real time atmospheric data in QGIS, namely wind vectors. I haven't found anything good yet.

Answer (score 5):

[NOAA's NowCoast](https://nowcoast.noaa.gov/help/#!section=mapservices) service  provides a real(ish) time wind speed as a WMS layer.

Comment: how reliable are NOAA's wms servers?

Comment: they are up most of the time - there's a mailing list you can subscribe to for notifications of outages

Answer (score 1):

Environment Canada offers a free public WMS / WFS / WCS server with hundreds of layers focused on numerical weather prediction models and observations data. It includes layers for winds for the whole world, along with several related products (e.g. winds at several altitudes, wind gusts, etc).

The server: http://geo.weather.gc.ca/geomet/
The documentation: http://www.ec.gc.ca/meteo-weather/default.asp?lang=En&n=C0D9B3D8-1

Hope this helps! -- Alex