# Looking for a wind WMS for Europe and Africa

Tags: data, wms, europe, africa

I was looking for a wind WMS but couldn't find. I wanted a wind WMS for Europe and Africa. Does anyone know about any?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit on what you are looking for specifically? From what I can tell is that you want wind data in the form of a Web Mapping Service?

Comment: Yes , i want daily updated wind information .. can be WMS , WFS or even raster or vectorial graphics mapping of wind. ty

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I get a WMS or WFS for near-real time Wind (atmospheric) data?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24275/where-can-i-get-a-wms-or-wfs-for-near-real-time-wind-atmospheric-data)

Comment: its something like that but for land , to add more context i'm developing a GIS to monitor fires so wind information is usefull.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said "raster graphics", you could use a "winds aloft" chart (for the ground level - "SFC".

Here is an example for Europe:
http://21weather.us.af.mil/wxdata/201207/26/MODEL-DATA/EUROPE/051848Z_21OWS_EUROPE_MODEL-DATA_UKMO-GLOBAL_WIND-TEMP_SFC_00_00Z.png

More at http://21weather.us.af.mil/index.cfm?section=Winds

The useful part about these is that they'll provide predictions, and they're gridded.

The less useful part is that they're rasters. The same information can be obtained (at much better resolution) in GRIB (gridded binary). One source is http://om.yr.no/verdata/ - the website requires Norwegian, or guesswork, to figure out what to download.

Comment: The http://21weather.us.af.mil/index.cfm?section=Winds site seems to have gone away. Is there a replacement site?

Comment: http://www.flyingineurope.be/aviation_weather_maps.htm suggests not, but might be useful depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the weather layer of google maps.
it contains data about temperatures (°C), wind speeds (and possibly also wind directions), etc.